# Laravel: How to use function of relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm facing a situation where a I have to call a function from the controller of a relation instance. For better explanation I will write an example below

I have a `Article` controller in which I have a `preview()` function.

A `User` can have multiple `Article`.

Let's say that the `preview()` function parse a text and replace special pieces of text by the user's name.

So my function will looks like this

```
//In ArticleController
public function preview(Article $article , User $user){
    return str_replace("username", $user->name , $article->text);
}
```

But for a specific situation I want to display a preview of the article when I list all the users

So in UserController

```
public function index(){
    foreach( User::all() as $user){
        echo $user->articles[0]->preview( ... );
    }
}
```

Obviously this piece of code will not work.

But I'm more looking of the way to proceed when I face this kind demand.

Should I create a Repository? Use this `preview()` function somewhere else? Or Is it just a bad practice to do that? What's the best approach or way of thinking when we face this?

Or maybe I'm just missing something important in Laravel's ORM. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Article is a model. So you have to add hasMany relation to User (user has many articles). Inside article you have to add preview function. In this case you will be able to find $user->article (or user->articles) and run ->preview function. This is the easiest solution I guess.

You can also add custom attribute like getPreviewAttribute and append it to article model. This way you would have $user->article->preview.

Comment: So I assume that the `preview` function should be in the Model and not the Controller. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, or use the custom attribute getPreviewAttribute, this way you will be able to reference it as attribute and not a function.